# Editar Imagem no banco de dados quando campo for vazio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um código que faz upload de imagem. No banco de dados funcionou lindamente. Agora preciso fazer um código que só altera a imagem quando esta for selecionada. Ou seja, no meu caso, quando altero um registo, obrigatoriamente tem que selecionar o campo imagem. Caso contrário, este fica sem imagem. Segue o código do *Controller*, **Action** `Edit`:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(Funcionario funcionario)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (funcionario.File == null)
            {

                funcionario.Foto = funcionario.Foto;
                funcionario.Freguesia = funcionario.Freguesia;
                funcionario.Concelho = funcionario.Concelho;

                db.Entry(funcionario).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {

                byte[] data = new byte[funcionario.File.ContentLength];
                funcionario.File.InputStream.Read(data, 0, funcionario.File.ContentLength);
                funcionario.Foto = data;

                db.Entry(funcionario).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();

            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(funcionario);
    }
```

Segue *View* `Create`:

```
<td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Foto)</td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.File, new { Type="file"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Foto)

        </td>
```

.....

Comment: Poderia esclarecer um pouco mais? Que campo é esse que você precisa selecionar?  Explique um pouco mais

Comment: Meu problema e nesse trecho ali caso eu não seleciono novo imagem para editar que ele recopera a imagem que esta na bd:
            if (funcionario.File == null)
            {       funcionario.Foto = funcionario.Foto;

Answer (score 1):

Tem várias coisas bem erradas aqui:

```
funcionario.Foto = funcionario.Foto;
funcionario.Freguesia = funcionario.Freguesia;
funcionario.Concelho = funcionario.Concelho;
```

Essa atribuição não faz o menor sentido.

Todo o seu código pode ser alterado para o seguinte:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Funcionario funcionario)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (funcionario.File != null && funcionario.File.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[funcionario.File.ContentLength];
            funcionario.File.InputStream.Read(data, 0, funcionario.File.ContentLength);
            funcionario.Foto = data;
        }

        db.Entry(funcionario).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(funcionario);
}
```

Apenas definindo sua foto como um array de bytes vazio já é suficiente.

Comment: Muito Obrigado isso me ajudou na organização e lógica.Mas o que eu quero  ali (funcionario.Foto = new byte[0];) não é colocar vazio mas deixar    o que já estava ou seja não fazer nada.

Comment: @Evandrobarros Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Agradeço mas não funcionou

Comment: Para mais informação O atributo foto é byte (public byte[] Foto { get; set; })

Answer (score 0):

desse jeito funcionou Obrigado a todos, algum sugestão?

```
[HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "SuperAdmin, Admin")]
    public ActionResult Edit(Funcionario funcionario)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (funcionario.File != null && funcionario.File.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[funcionario.File.ContentLength];
                funcionario.File.InputStream.Read(data, 0, funcionario.File.ContentLength);
                funcionario.Foto = data;

                db.Entry(funcionario).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {

                db.Entry(funcionario).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.Entry(funcionario).Property(m => m.Foto).IsModified = false;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }


            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(funcionario);
    }
```